# How to disable fire from generating in Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So im making heaven in minecraft by changing nether textures.

And it would be stupid that fire generates in nether (now heaven)....

Comment: Have you considered simply going to a spot a few hundred thousands blocks from where you're building and putting down some nether blocks there, then link them through the nether as some sort of purgatory?

Comment: Maybe but i was going to finish heaven first

Comment: You misunderstand me. Instead of making heaven in the Nether, make heaven on Minecraftia a hundred thousand blocks away from where you're building your world so you don't have to deal with the peculiarities of the Nether, like no water, no beds, constant fires, zombie pigmen spawning, ghasts, randomly exploding ores, tons of lava,...

Comment: I think that OP is trying to create a new texture pack for all to enjoy, and not just a map. Maybe with command-block mods, and therefore creating a heaven in his world would not fit.
I presume.

Comment: @creulcat if he's making a texture pack disabling fire is not an option.

Comment: @Arperum I know. But I'm just trying to guess and clarify his question

Comment: Like @Arperum said, you cannot do this with commands or a texture pack. You will need to create a mod that overrides fire generation.

Comment: Why don't you change the lava texture so it looks like water (or something that usually pours in heaven)?

Comment: Is the Aether mod still supported? That one was great. Really resembled heaven aswell

Comment: Try retexturing fire to something like "The Punishment Of God"-ishy or "Pure Heavenly Knowledge"-ishy

Comment: Thanks from the all support you gave me lots of ideas! Maybe i release the texture pack..Who knows?

Comment: @Nzall you misunderstand me...I meant on changing textures (just keepin it simple) not taking 1 week for crap and using worldedit.

Comment: I guess im just gonna edit fire texture to be a cloud or something just gimme ideas in comments

Comment: make it something that doesn't look out of place but still looks like it will hurt you. maybe a bright floating ball?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove fire inertly by placing a command block at spawn that is REPEATING, UNCONDITIONAL, and ALWAYS ACTIVE witch has the command

`/execute @e ~ ~ ~ fill ~10 ~10 ~10 ~-10 ~-10 ~-10 minecraft:air 0 replace minecraft:fire`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gamerule `/gamerule doFireTick false` to stop fire from starting, but this will stop fire from putting itself out. If you have world edit I'd select as much area as possible and do `//replace fire air`. But as other people have pointed out, if you are making a texture pack you can't disable fire from there. *(Other than making it a completely invisible texture and making it's sound file completely mute. However, if players walk into the block with fire they will take fire damage.)*

Comment: Will worth to try out.And yes i have worldedit ill tell ya what happened!